# Ubuntu pc doesn't boot from the second hd (Debian)

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, debian

On my PC I have two physical HDs: 160 + 40 GB. On the first HDD I have Ubuntu and it is running without problems (it's the one I'm using..).

I installed Debian on the second HD without particular problems, but I'm not able to boot with it.

I'm using the main Ubuntu grub to start the Debian one. With different grub configurations I received `Error 21 (selected disk does not exist)` or`Error 15 (File not found)`. For the main HDD I'm using (hd0,0), and for the second HDD I'm using (hd1,0) names.

If I declare root (hd1,0) I receive:

> Error 21 selected disk does not exist.

If I declare UUID=xxxxxx I receive

> Error 15: file not found

Ubuntu has grub1 and the debian has grub2.

If I type `fdisk -l`. I see two disks (sda and sdb). The BIOS shows only one disk (I guess the first disk). Is this correct?

How can I boot the second distribution?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and Debian are you using? PLease paste the complete output of `fdisk -l`. And, **why Ubuntu uses grub 1**?

Comment: It is too long for a comment ... and i cannot write an answer .. the grub is 0.97

Comment: Now i changed the bios settings and when i select: 'code'
title  Debian 7.1.0, kernel 3.2.0-4-686
uuid  67a2737d-5f71-4d98-9d23-4fbfae73af48
kernel  /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae root=UUID=67a2737d-5f71-4d98-9d23-4fbfae73af48 ro quiet
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
i have 'boot from (hd1,0) ext4 67a2.... Error 15: File not found

Comment: Just a question: grub 0.97 supports ext4 ?

Comment: you can edit your question and add the information, and only `grub 0.97-29ubuntu47` supports ext4.

Comment: Mine is grub 0.97-29ubuntu66. Is the /boot/.. syntax correct for the second hd? I double checked the filenames and they are correct ..

Comment: but, **why are you using grub 1 instead grub 2**? IMO, if you just install grub 2 your problem will go away.

Comment: i run boot-repair and i guess that it forced the start of the GRUB2. Now both Ubuntu and Debian run from that

Answer (score 2):

The OP appears to have solved the problem by running [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), as reported in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334183/ubuntu-pc-doesnt-boot-from-the-second-hd-debian#comment426150_334183):

> i run boot-repair and i guess that it forced the start of the GRUB2.
>   Now both Ubuntu and Debian run from that

Another possible solution, as [Braiam suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334183/ubuntu-pc-doesnt-boot-from-the-second-hd-debian/334794#comment426097_334183), may be to install GRUB2 manually, rather than using Boot-Repair. (And then to make sure that GRUB2 is written to the MBR and updated, and that the original "GRUB1" installation is no longer written automatically to the MBR.)